# How to obtain a dynamic threshold for contour detection in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In my image database, there is a need to 1) **detect** if there is a flake (a very black contour) or not in an image and also 2) find a minimum closing circle to **measure** the radius of the flake.

However, the images come with slightly different illuminations.

Here are some examples:

This one is very easy to either detect and measure:

[image]

But these ones are more difficult:

[image]   [image]   [image]

My initial thought is to use a threshold related to the **average value of pixels** of images.

Is there any other way of computing such a dynamic threshold in OpenCV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding) or [Otsu's thresholding](https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/07-thresholding/). To satisfy your requirements for #1, we can use a minimum threshold area to determine if the flake exists. For #2, once we detect the contour, we can use moments to determine the radius. Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale and median blur
- Adaptive threshold
- Morph close to smooth image
- Dilate to enhance contour
- Find contours and sort using contour area

---

The main idea is to use a large median blur to remove the noise then adaptive threshold.
Here's the results for each for your four pictures. For some of your pictures, the black spot was not actually a circle, it was more of a oval shape. You can decide what you want to do with that situation.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('4.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 25)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,27,6)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
dilate = cv2.dilate(close, kernel, iterations=2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:10]

minimum_area = 500
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > minimum_area:
        # Find centroid
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 20, (36, 255, 12), 2) 
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.putText(image, 'Radius: {}'.format(w/2), (10,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (36,255,12), 2)
        break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must start with a thresholding

[Here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) you have some thresholding, you can choose the one you want, with good parameters, most of the noise will go.

Then you can do en [edge](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html) detection

Finally, hough transform seems to best the best approach to detect circles (noise will be remove by the parameters of the [hough](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html) circle transform).

You can set a minimal and a maximal radius, so if you have an idea of the average radius, you can adjust it this way.